# Rewrite to previous folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I used to have this structure:

`mysite (root)
  L private
    L login.php
    L logout.php
    L db
      L manage_db.php
    L one-client.com
    L other-client.com
    L uploads
  L public
    L assets, etc.`

But now that has changed to this:

`mysite (root)
  L private
    L app-core (new folder)
        L login.php
        L logout.php
        L db
          L manage_db.php
    L one-client.com
    L other-client.com
    L uploads
  L public
    L assets, etc.`

What I need is rewrite the URL for being able to access to the login file from `mysite.com/private/login` instead of `mysite.com/private/app-core/login`. I tried this but is not working:

`RewriteRule ^private/app-core/(.*)$ /private/$1 [L,NC,R=302]`

Comment: @anubhava Yep, they all are pointing to the previous paths.

Comment: I tried `RewriteRule ^private/(.*)$ /private/app-core/$1 [L,NC,R=302]` but still not working. Throw 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^private/app-core/(.*)$ /private/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

This rule is doing reverse actually. You can just use this rule to change old `/private/login` URLs to new ones with `/app-core` in between for **a given set of URLs**:

```
RewriteRule ^private/(?!app-core|one-client\.com|uploads)(.*)$ /private/app-core/$1 [NC,L]
```

This will do correct redirection.

`(?!app-core)` is negative lookahead which means we don't have `app-core` after `/private/`

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but is not working as expected. When I access to `mysite.com/private/` the server redirects me to `mysite.com/private/app-core/`.

Comment: Yep, but wasn't working. Now I'm using this and is working as expected: `RewriteRule ^private/(?!app-core)(.*)$ /private/app-core/$1 [QSA,L]`.

Comment: No, I wanted the URL rewrite.

Comment: Now I have other issue. Using this rule: `RewriteRule ^private/(?!app-core)(.*)$ /private/app-core/$1 [QSA,NC,L]` this URL is not working: `mysite.com/private/one-client.com` neither is `mysite.com/private/another-client.com`. Without the rule is working but the `/app-core/` directory is not (this means, for example `mysite.com/private/login` is not getting the resources from `mysite.com/private/app-core/login`).

Comment: Correct, no `app-core` in between. Please check my question and the files structure.

Comment: Seems too much specific. If I add a new folder (I already have more folders than "db" and more files than "login.php" and "logout.php") should I add them into that regex?

Comment: Yes, it has to be specific. Either we can get it by excluding some known paths or by including some known paths. Whatever is is shorter list, just go with that. If there are only 3 folders to be excluded as `one-client.com,other-
 client.com, uploads` then we can have an exclusion rule.

Comment: Well, this seems to work: `RewriteRule ^private/(?!app-core)(?!one-client.com)(?!uploads)(.*)$ /private/app-core/$1 [QSA,NC,L]`

Comment: Nice! Just one question, why `[NC,L]` instead of `[QSA,NC,L]`? I mean, I may need QSA.

Comment: Because `QSA` is only needed when we are using query parameters in target URI. Otherwise original query string is appended to target automatically.